# Is my relationship level affected by only my actions?

Tags: simcity-social

In SimCity Social, you have a relationship type (good or bad) and level. I have noticed that the relationship type can be changed by the other party. For example, if I visit someone's city and remain neutral, after they visit me, it's possible for my relationship with them to become good or bad. I've also noticed that my persistent positive actions in an unfriendly city was able to change our relationship to good, visible on both of our UIs.

However, how far does this go? Does this only apply to changing the relationship type? Does it also apply to relationship levels (i.e. from Frenemies to Enemies)? What about experience points towards each level (shared between both parties rather than individual values)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some quick testing, me and my Twin City realized that the relationship is shared by the both of us.